# Sublime Text: Add character in column position

Tags: python, comments, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I have a Python file with a few hundred lines of code.  The longest line is 146 characters.  How would I put `#` in column 200 down the whole file within Sublime Text?  Preferably with one or two Sublime Text commands?

`1                                                           200`

`print("Hello world!")                                       #`

Comment: What do you mean in column 200? Do you want to fill up with whitespaces lines smaller than 200 characters?

Comment: @BPL I added a few lines in the original question to hopefully provide a better example.  I didn't put `#` in the true column 200 position in the above, just move it over to visually show what I was trying to ask.

Comment: What does this have to do with Sublime Text?

Comment: @MattDMo I was hoping to have the solution in Sublime Text.  I, apprentely, was not clear in that request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. Note that this writes to a new file: let me know if you want me to modify so that it overwrites the existing file:

```
data = []
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
  data = [line[:-1] + ' ' * (200 - len(line)) + '#\n' for line in f]

with open('new_data.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.writelines(data)
```

Note that this will have just append the "#" at the end of the line (regardless of column number) if the line length >= 200.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
N = 200
output = [l.rstrip() for l in f]
output = ["{0}#{1}".format(
    l[:len(l[:N])] + ' ' * (N - len(l[:N])), l[N:]) for l in output]

print("\n".join(output))
```

Or written differently:

```
N = 200
output = []
for l in f:
    l = l.rstrip()
    l1 = len(l[:N])
    output.append("{0}#{1}".format(l[:l1] + ' ' * (N - l1), l[N:]))

print("\n".join(output))
```